# Building SDL2 using hunter

Tags: c++

I'm trying to include SDL2 using the Hunter package manager.

```
hunter_add_package(sdl2)
find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

The package is downloaded, but the include dir is not being defined, so this does nothing

```
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

and the compile fails, on trying to #include SDL.

If i manually install SDL2, fx using brew install sdl2, and manually set the include path and link library, everything works. But I would like it to work using the package manager.

The cmake . command does show the following, not sure its related:

```
-- [hunter] SDL2_ROOT: /Users/martin/.hunter/_Base/9b96c37/6b5f9d6/aceec4e/Install (ver.: 2.0.7-p3)
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  CMake variable SDL2_ROOT is set to:

    /Users/martin/.hunter/_Base/9b96c37/6b5f9d6/aceec4e/Install

  Environment variable SDL2_ROOT is set to:

    /Users/martin/.hunter/_Base/9b96c37/6b5f9d6/aceec4e/Install

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Using cmake . -Wno-dev does make the warning disapear, but still no luck finding the includes.

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that warning is very related. You should set the CMP0074 policy to the NEW behavior.

Comment: using cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 OLD) removes the error, but still the SDL2 headers are not found.

Comment: The OLD behavior is to ignore the variable. Set it to the NEW behavior, as I said.

Comment: you are right. cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW) is the answer and on include_directories needed, just works. Will you post an answer?

Comment: You should probably file a bug about this with the hunter project. They claim CMake 3.2 is the minimal version while using functionality introduced in CMake 3.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that warning is very related. You should set the CMP0074 policy to the NEW behavior:

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
```

That will make it honour the settings offered by the `SDL_ROOT` variable.